# How to Pass Input Parameters by URL in BIRT?

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I am new to BIRT reporting. In my BIRT report I have two input parameters. I want to pass these two input parameters to the server through the query string (in the URL).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the problem is just get the right URL, this would be something like:

"YOUR_SERVER/your_birt_app/run?__report=ReportName.rptdesign&Name_Parameter1=Value1&Name_Paremeter2=Value2".

The "run" method is one of the methods mapped in the BIRT Viewer Servlet. There are two others: "frameset" and "preview".

You can check these informations in: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage2.2.php

Comment: what i need is when user clicks on report name link,ideally report should be displayed in a pdf format

Comment: @vivek...
You can add this parameter to your URL:    
__format=pdf. 
      So... something like: "YOUR_SERVER/your_birt_app/run?__report=ReportName.rptdesign&Name_Parameter1=Value1&Name_Paremeter2=Value2__format=pdf"...
You can check the formats and all parameters that you can use in your report call in the same page I sent before: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage2.2.php

Comment: You can set format in anywhere of your URL... It's like a regular html parameter, so you dont need to worry about the place to put it. BIRT will get it anyway.

Comment: currently i am calling like this.."http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=billreport.rptdesign&__format=pdf"  this one i have to change it to something like this.."http://localhost:8080/birt/run?__report=billreport.rptdesign&Name_Parameter1=value1&name_parameter_2=value2__format=pdf" .....am i correct??

Comment: It's just a normal link... all you have to do is add new parameters (in this case, format) in this link...

Comment: @Fera..i have one more doubt..i have to pass one parameter through querystring and other parameter i want to give it through input parameter window(using birt viewer).How can i do this??

Comment: @vivek... That's possible. It's about the design of your report. The parameter that you want to pass on URL, you will set it on report design (in the parameter window) as: "is Required" = no and "Hidden" = yes (the combo boxes). The parameter that you want the user choose (the parameter's window of BIRT), you will set as: "is Required" = yes and "Hidden" = no. These configs will prompt just the second parameter, so you can set the first one on URL.

Comment: How can I pass input parameter in a birt file by using batch? I am talking about the BIRT runtime engine. There is a genReport.bat script, which is working perfectly. But I dont know, how to pass parameter, and how to use them in the report

Answer (score 0):

Hakre..

If you are using static parameter then those parameter can be passed in the following way:
"http://yourcompleteurl&parametername1=value1&parametername2=value2".

Comment: I have to send parameters like: "Prashant Kumar. & Nishant Kumar" as one parameter and the report is not working. if I paste the same value in the prompt box it works. I want help with how to make it work for url. I guess the Issue here is "&"

Comment: Got it has to replace with %26.