# How to pass input parameters by cmd (BIRT runtime engine) in BIRT?

Tags: batch-file, birt

It is possible to pass parameter to a report on URL: [How to Pass Input Parameters by URL in BIRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953007/how-to-pass-input-parameters-by-url-in-birt)

But i am currently using the BIRT runtime engine to create a report:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-4.8.0-201806261756/birt-runtime-4.8.0-20180626.zip

The call is:

```
genReport.bat -f PDF -o output.pdf test.rptdesign
```

My question: Is it possible to pass input parameter? And how can i fetch and use them in the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

1) Set a Report Parameter in BIRT itself.

[image: Report Parameter]

2) Use the variable (e.g. params["Test"].value) in the script

3) Pass the parameter with -p in the batch call. See:

`genReport.bat -f PDF -o paramTest.pdf -p "Test=3" test.rptdesign`